# SVG: text in opposite direction

Tags: css, text, svg

I am looking for a solution to include a *SVG text tag* on the right site of my SVG graphic so I typed in:

```
<svg width = "300" height = "200">
  <text x = "200" y = "100">Foo</text>
</svg>
```

which rendered like this:

```
example 1
=========

+--------------------+
|                    |
|                    |
|             Foo -> |
|                    |
|                    |
+--------------------+
```

The problem is, I'd like to have the text direction (or whatever thats called) to be from the right site to the left,

```
example 2
=========

+--------------------+
|                    |
|                    |
|             <- Foo |
|                    |
|                    |
+--------------------+
```

so I tried two things so far:

1. `<text x = "200" y = "100" writing-mode = "rl-tb">Foo</text>`as described on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/writing-mode)
2. `<text x = "200" y = "100" text-anchor = "end">Foo</text>` as described on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor)

Both results looked like **example 1**.
Does anyone know a solution to get **example 2** as result?

Comment: do you want the text like "ooF"? (from right to left)

Comment: Nope, I want it to be readable from **left to right** ("Foo"), but the text container to go from **right to left**.

Comment: so the *SVG text tag* should be **flexible** in the **left direction** but **static** in the **right direction** since I dont know how long the text will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want text-anchor="end" like so I think.

```
<svg width = "300" height = "200">
    <rect width="300" height="200" fill="yellow" opacity="0.5"/>
  <text x = "300" y = "100" text-anchor="end">Foo</text>
</svg>
```